# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to generate quickstart-web.xml

Tags: google-app-engine, google-managed-vm

Managed VM's require in your `appengine-web.xml` or it's `app.yaml` equivalent:

```
<beta-settings>
  <setting name="java_quickstart" value="true" />
</beta-settings>
```

And you use try to deploy you get this RuntimeException, what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of the deployment process, both the `gcloud preview app deploy` and `mvn gcloud:deploy` commands will launch jetty locally as part of the discovery of your annotations.  If there is an error in your code it will crash.  For example, in your `contextedDestroyed` or `contextInitialized` methods they will crash.

If you are using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), it is possible to debug this issue by:

For Java SDK 1.9.32:

`java -jar ~/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.32/appengine-java-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.32/lib/java-managed-vm/appengine-java-vmruntime/quickstartgenerator.jar target/myExplodedWar-1.0-SNAPSHOT`

For Java SDK 1.9.33:

`java -jar ~/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.33/appengine-java-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.33/lib/java-managed-vm/appengine-java-vmruntime/quickstartgenerator.jar target/myExplodedWar-1.0-SNAPSHOT ~/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.33/appengine-java-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.33/lib/jetty-base-sdk/etc/webdefault.xml`

We expect this to be fixed in Java SDK 1.9.35

Comment: I get this issue by running the quick start example provided by GCloud...? (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/quickstart)